# MSSQL use result from case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
SELECT .....
    'NewReserveSum' = 
case 
    when h.ApprovedCurrencyID = 417 then new.ReserveSumV 
    else [dbo].[GetCurrencyRate](h.ApprovedCurrencyID, @PresentDate) * new.ReserveSumV 
end,
    (o.ReserveSummN - NewReserveSum) as 'DifferenceReserveSummN'
    
FROM ......
```

I want to use the ** NewReserveSum ** variable in the following columns, but I got an error:

> Invalid column name 'NewReserveSum'

How can I do it correctly in MSSQL?

Answer (score -1):

In SQL, `=` is comparison, not assignment

In a SELECT statement, you can use AS to give a name top an expression column:

```
SELECT
case 
    when h.ApprovedCurrencyID = 417 then new.ReserveSumV 
    else [dbo].[GetCurrencyRate](h.ApprovedCurrencyID, @PresentDate) * new.ReserveSumV 
end as NewReserveSum,
...
```

Comment: case when h.ApprovedCurrencyID = 417 then new.ReserveSumV 
 else [dbo].[GetCurrencyRate](h.ApprovedCurrencyID, @PresentDate) * new.ReserveSumV end as NewReserveSum,
 (o.ReserveSummN - NewReserveSum) as 'DifferenceReserveSummN',I have already done this but got the same error

Comment: *"In SQL, = is comparison, not assignment"* Not true. `{Alias} = {Expression}` (which aliases) is valid syntax, as is `{Variable} = {Expression}` (which assigns). Some people (not myself) prefer using the `=` over `AS` for aliasing, such as Bertrand: [Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Comment: [= (Assignment Operator) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/assignment-operator-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)